# Load in many values at once using a query

Tags: sql, delphi

I am using a program coded in Delphi 7 (sadly I cannot use a newer version for this program) which considers individual persons. For each person, I need to load in a bunch of values (0 to 90 at most, with the exact number depending on the person; non-fixed) which are used later in the code. After trying out a number of things, including loading in via Excel (which was horribly slow) someone suggested loading in the data through Access. I managed to get the following code so far:

```
 MainConnection   : TADOConnection;  
 Table            : TADOTable;
 StrConnection    : String;


//I first open a connection to load the values in from
MainConnection:=TADOConnection.Create(nil);
StrConnection:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\test.mdb;Mode=Read;Persist Security Info=False;';

MainConnection.LoginPrompt:=False;
MainConnection.ConnectionString:= StrConnection;
MainConnection.Connected:=True; 

Table:=TADOTable.Create(nil);
Table.Connection :=MainConnection; 

Table.TableName := 'Sheet1';
Table.Open;

// I get the first three values which I absolutely require

Firstvalue    :=   Table.Fields[0].value;           
Secondvalue   :=   Table.Fields[1].value;           
Thirdvalue    :=   Table.Fields[2].value;           


//Whether I need additional values depends on the first and second values; if the first is a specific value 
// I do not need any of the other ones
nrofvaluestoget :=    round((Secondvalue-Firstvalue));
   if  (Firstvalue = 100) then   nrofvaluestoget:= 0;

     if   (nrofvaluestoget>0) then begin
for k := 0 to (nrofvaluestoget) do begin
Valueholder[k]  :=  Table.Fields[5+k].value; ;               // values for the valueholder


 Table.Next; //Go to next person
```

This links the access database and technically does what I want. However, while it is quicker than loading in an excel file it's still quite slow due to the "nrofvaluestoget" loop. Skipping that and loading in all values for a person at once would speed up the process quite a bit.

As far as I'm aware this may be possible using a SQL query; something akin to: 'SELECT * FROM Sheet1'. However, I am not familiar with SQL, let alone linking it through Delphi 7. Is it even possible to get all the values at once and assign them immediately to the "Valueholder" with Delphi 7? Or at the very least, is there some way to speed up the code above that I'm not aware of? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Per Juan's suggestion I added some additional descriptions with regards to the database.

I posted a picture as an example of the database as I was unable to embed one or create a decent looking table.  [image: Example table]

Let's say I have three persons. Person 1 would have 15 as a first age, and 16 as the second age. 
In the current loop, Valueholder would have the value 2 at index 0, and value 0 at index 1. Person 1 has no further ages with values, so these are not considered in the loop.

When the next person is evaluated, all indices of Valueholder are set to their base value (blank).

Person 2 has 18 as the first age and 20 as the second. Valueholder then gets 3 values, namely: the value 8 at index 0, the value 4 at index 1 and the value 2 at index 2.

For the last person, all indices of Valueholder are again reset to their base value.

Person 3 has 100 as a first age; this is an indication that this person has no values which need to be loaded, so Valueholder is blank

I hope this clarifies the question a bit.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1):

(if this is a one off import)
I would recommend exporting the data to a csv file and using TFileStream to read it in your Delphi program. This will be faster than having to connect to Access or SQL server or any database.